# Обработка писем от Yandex FBL

Tags: email, яндекс-почта

Я настраиваю сервер для выполнения email-рассылок нашим пользователям, поэтому использую все возможные способы, позволяющие свести к минимуму проблемы в плане спама.

У Yandex есть система уведомлений [FBL (Feedback Loop)](http://yandexfbl.senderscore.net/faq.php), которая отправляет на указанный почтовый адрес отчеты о добавлении пользователями в спам писем, которые пришли из определенной сети (сетей), чтобы позже по этим отчетам рассыльщик удалил из своего списка рассылки адреса этих пользователей (чтобы опять не слать письма тем, кто добавляет их в спам).

Моя проблема заключается в том, что в этих отчетах нет ничего, что могло бы идентифицировать письмо и отправителя. Судя по всему, Яндекс (или returnpath.net, если судить по заголовкам отчетов) скрывает адреса пользователей, записывая вместо них лапшу наподобие ca2b45...@email.xxx ([32-символьный хэш-как-md5]@email.xxx), в том числе в заголовках To и Original-Rcpt-To, а также не передает из оригинального сообщения ничего, кроме темы (Subject).

На странице [FAQ по YandexFBL](http://yandexfbl.senderscore.net/faq.php) есть вопрос "Как мне следует обрабатывать жалобы из отчета FBL?", в ответе на который написано:

"Интернет-провайдер может отредактировать части оригинальных сообщений для защиты личных данных своих пользователей. В случе, если Интернет-провайдер удалил адреса подписчиков из отчета FBL, Вам следует включить контрольные ID, уникальные для получателей в Вашей базе, и сопоставить с теми сообщениями, которые были отправлены адресату, чтобы отследить удаления. Уникальные ID получателей Вы можете добавить в тело сообщения, или создать специальный "X" заголовок: например, "X-SenderName-ClientID: 543432"."

Но проблема в том, что тело оригинального сообщения не пересылается, как и заголовков X-SenderName-ClientID / Message-ID / X-Feedback-ID / Feedback-ID. Все, что может распознать отправленное письмо, которое добавили спам - это его тема, но я не думаю, что добавлять в тему каждого сообщения какие-то идентификаторы - хорошая мысль.

К примеру, при работе с [Mail.ru FBL](https://help.mail.ru/mail-help/work/fbl) все происходит намного проще, так как у них в отчетах адрес пользователя не заменяется, а также передается оригинальный Message-ID

Кто сталкивался с проблемой, подскажите пожалуйста, как в отчеты от Yandex FBL добавить идентификатор сообщения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После некоторых поисков, нашел ответ:

На странице [Yandex Post Office - Troubleshooting](https://yandex.com/support/postoffice/troubleshooting.xml), в виде информационного сообщения в самом верху страницы (не в списке вопросов, как ожидалось) написано: "Yandex.Post Office team decided to stop access to user spam-complaints list. FBL report will soon lose original Message-ID and another links. We concluded that this information can be used to the detriment of Yandex.Mail users."

Другими словами, Yandex намеренно выдрал из отчетов адреса и любые данные, которые могут идентифицировать письмо, оставив только информацию о том, что "Сообщение с такой-то темой кто-то засунул в спам". Полагаю, единственное их применение теперь - подсчет тех самых добавлений в спам, а в случае с массовым получением таких отчетов - сигнал к действию ("Кто-то шлет спам из вашей сети с вот такой темой, EOF").

Вкратце, ответ на вопрос: "В отчет никак (нормальным способом) нельзя добавить идентификатор сообщения".

Можно добавить идентификатор в заголовок сообщения, так как он приходит в отчете, но это может негативно сказаться на рассылках (если не ошибаюсь, многие требуют, чтобы темы рассылок всем адресантам были одинаковыми).

Еще несколько выводов - на странице Yandex FBL FAQ размещены устаревшие данные, и автоматизировать обработку сообщений о спаме от Yandex не получится.

Answer (score 0):

Да, автор вопроса (ответа) абсолютно прав. 
Яндекс в плане предоставления информации в отчете FBL самый ... из всех остальных крупных почтовых сервисов, которые предоставляют отчеты.

1. Использование для идентификации адресата дополнительной информации в теме письма (а это единственное поле, которое Яндекс не модифицирует в своем отчете), как было отмечено выше, приведет к негативным последствиям. Нужно придерживаться правила: одна рассылка - одинаковая тема писем.
2. По существу. Я смог решить данный вопрос только с помощью id письма который в заголовки прописывает почтовый сервер (Exim) и Яндекс его не трогает.
   Но здесь есть несколько неудобств (и по опыту использования данного алгоритма - весьма глобальные):

   - нужно парсить логи почтового сервера и извлекать от туда данные - пару: Email получателя и id письма.
   - нужно где-то хранить эти данные.

К сожалению, это дополнительная нагрузка на ресурсы сервера, и другого варианта я пока не нашел.